# Identify currentUIculture being used in a spfx webpart

Tags: reactjs, typescript, spfx, currentuiculture

Adapting the pnp dev spfx webpart react Rhythym of Business Calendar(/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-rhythm-of-business-calendar) to have it multilangual I<m running into the issue of making momentJS also change language but I need to get the currentUIculture and I am running into a wall. Any help will be appreciated.

I tried _spPageContextInfo as well as this.context.PageContext.currentUICultureName.toString();

Comment: What have you tried so far?